# Entity Framework returns zero/null values for columns after 1st column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6.1.2, database-first.

In one situation, this linq to sql query:

```
 var data = from dl in ctx.ObjectContext.DocumentLines.Where(drow => drow.DocumentId == documentId)
                       join di in ctx.ObjectContext.DocumentsInfoes on dl.DocumentId equals di.Id
                       join ba in ctx.ObjectContext.Addresses on dl.DeliveryAddressId equals ba.Id into tba
                       from xba in tba.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       join sc in ctx.ObjectContext.SalesCategories on dl.SalesCategoryId equals sc.Id into tsc
                       from xsc in tsc.DefaultIfEmpty()

                       select new { Line = dl, DocumentInfo = di, DeliveryAddress = xba, SalesCategory = xsc };

            var abc = data.ToList();
```

is not working.

The first documentline is correctly bound, but subsequent rows have some NULL or zero properties. If I run the generated SQL query, all columns are present and correct.

Is this a bug in Entity Framework? I have  downloaded the EF source and I want to step into it to attempt to understand what's happening but don't know where to start looking.

The documentline table has a timestamp Version column for concurrency purposes. I have read a few similar issues where problems with a timestamp column, or other columns, (see [Entity Framework does not pull through data from some columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816266/entity-framework-does-not-pull-through-data-from-some-columns)) could cause subsequent columns to fail.

**EDIT**

On further investigation, it seems that, in the one call to this code that exhibits the problem, I can step over `var abc = data.ToList();` *without hitting any of the breakpoints* in the setters of the properties of the DocumentLine entity, in the data model. Bizarre. All other calls to the code hit the breakpoints. Why isn't it loading the entities?

Comment: I don't understand your point. I have a normalised database so it is inevitable that I am going to have to join entities to construct business objects. Include() and navigation properties have problems of their own. For me compile time checking and easy debugging are the big wins win EF.

Comment: You are using `outer join`, of course some colums can be null if it does not exist. My best bet is to copy paste that linq into linqpad and debug what is happening.

Comment: The documentlines always exist for a document and are always being joined. The problem is that the properties are not being set. I can pause execution and run the generated query just fine - all data returned perfectly. If you look at my edit I am saying that it seems EF doesn't even execute the generated query. I also tried testing in LinqPad - it works perfectly. As I said, this only happens in 1 scenario in my application.

Comment: you mentioned 'the one call to this code'... Does that mean it's not working for a given `documentID` or what? does the same exact code work sometimes but not others (like, given a different `documentID`)? Can you profile the DB and/or while debugging and get the actual SQL that's generated? The question that you linked to with a 'similar' problem was resolved by them restarting their PC, so I wouldn't really use that as an example of similar behavior.

Comment: @DrewJordan It's for the same document id. The sequence of operations that takes place is complex, but basically I am saving an object, and during that I load a document, at various points, to get some values, whixh included the linq above. One of these calls exhibits the problem. I'll grab the sql - I'll use  ObjectQuery.ToTraceString(). If I run the sql on its own it loads perfectly.

Comment: It isn't necessary to do the joins like this in code.  EF can handle all that for you if you let it.

Comment: @Amy do you mean via Navigation properties and Include()? I'm aware of that and I do use them, but there are problems with them - Navigation properties will typically pull in more data than you need. The code is frequently used so I prefer the efficiency of joins in this scenario (the data model is much bigger than i am showing here). I know there in Include to do eager loading but it has well documented performance issues and is difficult to get right. I'd like to keep this on topic please.

Comment: Here's another common misconception: "with Navigation Properties -- if you want joins -- you *have* to use Includes" ... this is just not true. If your projection at the end requires one or more columns from an Entity, that Entity will be joined in the generated query (whether you specify a `join` in EF or not). Let EF do the hard work.

Comment: This says it way better than I could: [LINQ `join` keyword less readable](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/). He doesn't stress it at the beginning, but does throughout the post, that using associations vs using joins generates *equivalent* SQL.